# How to choose the output vector size for metric learning?

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network, metric

In metric learning of e.g., MNIST images, a CNN projects a 28 x 28 image into a $d$-dimensional vector which gets passed to a metric learning loss function: minimize the Euclidean or cosine distance between these vectors if they're from the same digit, and maximize the distance if they're from different digits.

Now I'm doing machine learning (metric learning) and I'm faced with the problem: How best to choose the size of the output vector, $d$?

Because, if i chose big size: i have to have more epoch of learning before enough result
And i think: if I choose a small size, then there is a chance that I will not be able to create a final vector for a clear separation of objects from different groups.

What should i do?
How do I understand that the output vector size is not enough?
Such characteristics (dimensions) can only be selected, or maybe there is some kind of estimation formula or at least an upper bound on the number of parameters depending on the size of the image?

Comment: What do you mean by “output vector size”?

Comment: I mean how many dimensions our point(object) have.
For example: we can convert image (28*28) to vector (with k dimensions) and after using KNN for classification.

Comment: I noticed that for example, a vector with a large number of dimensions (for example 256) is used for faces,
but for numbers from MNIST, a vector with two dimensions (x;y) may be enough.
I modificate my question

Comment: I'm afraid it's not clear. Could you try to edit and clarify? Maybe you could give an example? Your comment is not clear because you give an example of 28x28 images and compare it to MNIST that also is 28x28, while you claim it has two dimensions.

Comment: @Tim "output vector size" = the dimensionality of / number of hidden units in the last layer. In metric learning of MNIST data, a CNN projects a 28 x 28 image into a, e.g., 2-dimensional vector which gets passed to a metric learning loss function: minimize the Euclidean or cosine distance between these vectors if they're from the same digit, and maximize the distance if they're from different digits. "output vector size" = 2 here.

Comment: @chicxulub the dimension depends on what you are predicting. E.g. if it's 5 class classification problem, it cannot be anything else than 5. You do not choose it.

Comment: @Tim In metric learning, we do not choose the number of classes, but choose the size of the last linear layer, the output of which is the desired vector.

Comment: Then, please edit your question to explain what exactly is your model and what is the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only paper I've seen which includes an experiment on this issue for CNNs is [*Facenet: A unified embedding for face recognition and clustering*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.03832)<sup>1</sup>. Table 5—

[image: table]

—demonstrates that differences are not significant for the $\text{VAL}$ metric, which is an accuracy metric for facial recognition tasks (see section 4).

> i have to have more epoch of learning before enough result

Indeed, the authors hypothesize in section 5.4 that the drop in $\text{VAL}$ from $256$ to $512$ dimensions may be explained by the fact that the latter model required "more training". It's unclear whether the Table 5 experiments hold the number of epochs constant, so it's unclear whether "more training" refers to more training data (because larger models generally require more training data) or more epochs. In either case, without concrete experiments, I'm not convinced that increases in embedding dimensionality warrant *significant* increases in training compute. The increase in parameter count going from $256$ to $512$ is $1024(512 - 256) = 262,144$ for their NN2 Inception model (see Table 2). So the relative increase in (trainable) parameter count for the whole model is roughly $262,144 / 7.6\text{M} \approx 3\%$. While parameter count is not a great proxy for model complexity<sup>2</sup>, this increase doesn't seem like something to worry about. An important consideration: if you're finetuning a pretrained CNN, the relative increase in trainable parameter count could be significant.

In conclusion, I wouldn't worry too much about setting the embedding dimensionality too low. Most of the learning happens in the CNN backbone, which  typically dwarfs the last linear/embedding layer. Go with a number which is in the ballpark of what worked for others who solved a task + data + architecture which is similar to yours, e.g., $[64, 512]$ if your images are faces. Half it if you're concerned that you don't have enough training data. If there isn't a relevant ballpark in the literature, then you'll have to do the hard work of validating one yourself. If there is one, the embedding dimensionality will be one of the last hyperparameters you need to tune, if at all.

### References

1. Schroff, Florian, Dmitry Kalenichenko, and James Philbin. "Facenet: A unified embedding for face recognition and clustering." Proceedings of the IEEE conference on computer vision and pattern recognition. 2015.
2. Nakkiran, Preetum, et al. "Deep double descent: Where bigger models and more data hurt." Journal of Statistical Mechanics: Theory and Experiment 2021.12 (2021): 124003.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!